# regular expression which does not match specific string in a line

Tags: regex

I have been trying for hours to get this working, can anyone assist me with a regex that will match the string "map" and "brand" in the text below. It should not match "reverse_map" line. So the first two lines are OK but not the third.

```
map             brand 
map             brand  
reverse_map     brand
```

Comment: Should it match `"map brandy"`? ie should each term be a whole word? Should it match `"brandy map"`? ie does order matter?

Answer (score 0):

If "map brand" is always the only string in the line, just use `^` and `$` to tell where are, respectively, the beginning and the end of the line:

```
^map[[:space:]]+brand$
```

Comment: map is always at the begging of the line  but brand is not always at the end of the line.

Comment: Then remove the "end of line" marker and anything can follow "brand"

Answer (score 0):

Use a word boundary to require the `m` in `map` not have a word character before it:

```
/\bmap brand/
```

https://regex101.com/r/wE9spT/1/

If you need something similar for `brand` to ensure, for example, `map brandfoo` doesn't get matched, add another word boundary at the end:

```
/\bmap brand\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`(?:\bmap\b.*\bbrand\b|\bbrand\b.*\bmap\b)`